# Reason of following C code compile error

Tags: c, compilation, syntax-error

```
‪#include‬ <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    char cValue='a';
    int iValue=1234567;
    long 1Value=7890123;
    float fValue=3.141592;
    double dValue=3.141592;
    char*string="korea";
    char buffer[100];

    sprintf(buffer,"char type is %c", cValue);
    puts(buffer);

    sprintf(buffer,"int type is %d", iValue);
    puts(buffer);

    sprintf(buffer,"long type is %1d", 1Value);
    puts(buffer);

    sprintf(buffer,"float type is %f", fValue);
    puts(buffer);

    sprintf(buffer,"double type is %e", dValue);
    puts(buffer);

    sprintf(buffer,"char* type is %s", string);
    puts(buffer);
}
```

when I compile with this code,
The syntax and other error occured.

What is the problem in this code?

Error messages:

```
76\76.c(7) : error C2059: syntax error : 'bad suffix on number'
76\76.c(7) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'
76\76.c(7) : warning C4091: ' ' : ignored on left of 'long ' when no variable is declared
76\76.c(7) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Value'
76\76.c(7) : error C2065: 'Value' : undeclared identifier
76\76.c(8) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
76\76.c(9) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
76\76.c(10) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
76\76.c(11) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
76\76.c(13) : error C2065: 'buffer' : undeclared identifier
76\76.c(13) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int '
76\76.c(13) : warning C4024: 'sprintf' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
76\76.c(14) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int '
76\76.c(14) : warning C4024: 'puts' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
76\76.c(16) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int '
76\76.c(16) : warning C4024: 'sprintf' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
76\76.c(17) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int '
76\76.c(17) : warning C4024: 'puts' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
76\76.c(19) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int '
76\76.c(19) : warning C4024: 'sprintf' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
76\76.c(19) : error C2059: syntax error : 'bad suffix on number'
76\76.c(19) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'Value'
76\76.c(19) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
76\76.c(20) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int '
76\76.c(20) : warning C4024: 'puts' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
76\76.c(22) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int '
76\76.c(22) : warning C4024: 'sprintf' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
76\76.c(22) : error C2065: 'fValue' : undeclared identifier
76\76.c(23) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int '
76\76.c(23) : warning C4024: 'puts' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
76\76.c(25) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int '
76\76.c(25) : warning C4024: 'sprintf' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
76\76.c(25) : error C2065: 'dValue' : undeclared identifier
76\76.c(26) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int '
76\76.c(26) : warning C4024: 'puts' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
76\76.c(28) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int '
76\76.c(28) : warning C4024: 'sprintf' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
76\76.c(28) : error C2065: 'string' : undeclared identifier
76\76.c(29) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int '
76\76.c(29) : warning C4024: 'puts' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
```

Comment: and what are those errors ?

Comment: `char*string="korea";` A space after `char*` will not kill you.

Comment: mention all the errors.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two errors:

1. `main` must return an `int`
2. Variable `1Value` is illegally named.  Identifiers cannot begin with anything other than a letter or underscore.

When you're trying to figure out what the syntax error is, start at the top.  Consider the error:

> 76\76.c(7) : error C2059: syntax error : 'bad suffix on number'

Go to line 7 and examine it:

```
long 1Value=7890123;
```

What can possibly be wrong with it?  Don't move from that line until you figure it out!  When you do.  Recompile and see if that fixes all your other errors.  If it doesn't, tackle the next first error.

Answer (score 6):

```
long 1Value=7890123;
```

You cannot use digit as the first character of variable name.

Comment: seems OP wanted to name it as `lValue` after checking `iValue` for int

Comment: It's best never to use l (ell) by itself, that is, without context.